# How to kill my running Android application?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application which has logout button. When I click on that I need to close my app completely (I don't want to run the app in background as well).

I tried with `System.exit(0)` and `finish()` as well.

Comment: "When I click on that I need to close my app completely (I don't want to run the app in background as well)" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare, That is log out button and the session should expire. That is reason I need to close it permanently

Comment: can u share ur androidmanifest file ? is <application
        android:killAfterRestore="true">

Comment: @PowerPc, I added this but no use

Comment: "the session should expire" -- this has nothing to do with "close my app". Do you think Web developers try to crash the user's browser to "close my [Web] app"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on your logout button try this code:

```
 finish();
 moveTaskToBack(true);
 System.exit(0);
```

i think this will not close your app completely but will exit from all of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a mechanism in place to close an application safely.

In the last Activity on the stack (usually the main, or just the first you have started) override the `onDestroy()` method.

You can either call the `System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)` which ensures that all objects will be finalized and garbage collected when the the application exits, or kill an application quickly via `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` if you prefer.

Comment: I tried with following code. But no use android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 0):

the finish()-method runs the destruction of the activity. so, it should be right here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, finish(); is not working for me.